# Missing \endcsname inserted. \end

Tags: errors

I am trying to import existing .tex files into a larger document, but I am running into this error.  How can I fix it?

[image: It produces "Missing \endcsname inserted. \end" about 100 times]

Below is the offending code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
    Some text here
    \import{Title page 20190322}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\import` requires two arguments.

Comment: also it's usually best to avoid spaces in filenames. Is theer any reason to use `import` rather than a standard `\input` here? also note that the image you show is just a (not very helpful) summary of the errors made by your editor, the error message from tex on teh console and the log file shows which command is not defined.